# The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Duration'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, openai-api

I upgraded my package chat_gpt_sdk to 2.0.4 and the flutter sdk to the latest version but now i get this error The argument type 'int' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Duration'. I need to be on this version to have access to the chatgpt turbo model. can anyone help me with this

```
      return 'Count: $count';
    }).take(10);

    openAI = OpenAI.instance.build(
      token: "$Apikey",
      baseOption: HttpSetup(
        receiveTimeout: 30000,
        connectTimeout: 5000,
        sendTimeout: 5000,

      ),
      isLogger: true,
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide `receiveTimeout` , `connectTimeout` and  `sendTimeout` in [`Duration`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Duration/Duration.html)

```dart
baseOption: HttpSetup(
  receiveTimeout: Duration(milliseconds: 30000),
  connectTimeout: Duration(seconds: 5),
  sendTimeout: Duration(seconds: 5),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Those timeout parameters take [Duration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Duration-class.html) objects

```
openAI = OpenAI.instance.build(
  token: "$Apikey",
  baseOption: HttpSetup(
    receiveTimeout: const Duration(milliseconds: 300000),
    connectTimeout: const Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
    sendTimeout: const Duration(milliseconds: 5000),

  ),
```